# Missing a Event with a EventHandler in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I recently created a WPF Game, where the last thing we added was a music, just an mp3 with a loop.

This is what I did to accomplish it.

```
Music = new MediaPlayer();
Music.Open(new Uri("Sounds/MyMusic.mp3", UriKind.Relative));
Music.MediaEnded += MusicEnded;
Music.Play();



private void MusicEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Music.Stop();
Music.Play();
}
```

The game have been behaving ok, and we used it for 3 days for more than 2 hours without a problem, but 1 of the days the music just stopped and the other sounds keep playing.

How could this happened? Can the event handler miss 1 event? in that case my code would stop working since no one monitor the EventHandler or the music.

How can I improve this code? or avoid this from happening?

Comment: Well you're asking why it would have stopped and not re-started, but then asked if the handler was missed...since the handler is what is stopping your music, I'd say the handler is being hit and something is causing an issue trying when calling `Play` again. Perhaps add some simple debugging outputs (e.g. Console.WriteLine(string.format("MUSICENDED CALLED at {0}", DateTime.Now)); ) to try and track it down.

Comment: Im asking if the event handler could miss 1 event, the music stop because it gets to the end not because i hit stop, stop just set the position property to the start.

Comment: OK...my advice still stands. If you put an output statement in, then you know that if the music stops and you have an output, the event was handled.

Comment: Yes Ryan Its a good idea to log whats its going on, and i did that already, but to know whats happening i need it to fail again, and havent been able to reproduce it testing, and i would not like it to happend again with 300 peopole watching the game and waiting to play i.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set Position poroperty when Music is ended without stopping and starting

For XNA mediaplayer you could use IsRepeating property
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.isrepeating.aspx

Comment: This is for the XNA MediaPlayer, the WPF Media Player does not have this property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.aspx documentation for the WPF

Comment: sorry I focused on "game" and miss "WPF"

Comment: I have the same problem setting the position Property, thats actually what the stop do.

Answer (score 2):

Do you start music from GUI thread?

If your GUI thread is busy doing someting else and missed event that why.
Maby adding some time taking extra loops and trying to repeat problem.

Another way to repeat:

```
private void MusicEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Music.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
    Music.Play();
}
```

Comment: I do use the same Gui Thread to start it, i just wasn't aware that it could actually lose it, and Changing the Position to 0 its the same that the stop